# MASM doesn't pause on ReadString and IF block is not being executed

Tags: if-statement, assembly, masm, irvine32, pause

1.) I am supposed to write a program that generates the following output:

`Enter a digit:  8`

`You entered a digit.`

`Do you want to run the program again (Y or N)?  Y`
(The user enters Y, so the **screen** **clears** and the programs runs again.)

`Enter a digit:  Q
You did not enter a digit.`

`Do you want to run the program again (Y or N)?  N`
(The user enters N, so the .REPEAT - .UNTIL loop ends.

2.)   Use a block-structured .IF statement,  or use jump instructions (I use both)

3.)   Use a  .REPEAT - .UNTIL  Directive to allow the user to run the program repeatedly.
-   If the user enters Y, then the screen clears and the program runs again.

However the problem I am running into is that my output doubles up on the consoles both the digitprompt and the runagain, meaning that it skips all the way to the end of the program bypassing the IF blocks along the way. How can I fix this please? I want it to pause appropriately on the way, and no, "WaitMsg" won't work here because I'm anticipating an input. Here is what the console looks like with a dumpregs wedged in-between the perpetrators:

```
Enter a digit:
  EAX=00000000  EBX=002E3000  ECX=0040100A  EDX=00406010
  ESI=0040100A  EDI=0040100A  EBP=0019FF80  ESP=0019FF74
  EIP=00403683  EFL=00000246  CF=0  SF=0  ZF=1  OF=0  AF=0  PF=1

Do you want to run the program again (Y or N)? _
```

ABOVE IS THE ERROR...

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.data
digitprompt BYTE "Enter a digit: ",0
userDig db 64 dup(?),0
runagain BYTE "Do you want to run the program again (Y or N)? ",0
characterans BYTE ?,0
digit BYTE "You entered a digit.",0
notdigit BYTE "You did not enter a digit.",0


.code
main PROC
.REPEAT
call Clrscr

mov edx, 0
mov edx, OFFSET digitprompt
call WriteString
mov edx, OFFSET userDig
call ReadString

.IF edx >= 0 
    jmp L1 
.ELSE
    jmp isNotDig
.ENDIF

L1: 
.IF edx <= 9 
    jmp isDig
.ELSE
    jmp isNotDig
.ENDIF

isDig: mov edx, OFFSET digit
jmp L2

isNotDig: mov edx, OFFSET notdigit

L2:
mov edx, OFFSET runagain
call WriteString
call ReadChar
mov characterans, al

.UNTIL characterans == 'N'


exit
main ENDP
END main
```

Comment: You still have the same bug as your previous question: `digit BYTE "You entered a digit."` is missing a `, 0`.  So is `notdigit`.  You might have other bugs as well; use the debugger to see the path of execution and get clues about *why* it goes where it does.  Also, using `jmp` as the only thing inside a `.IF`/ `.ELSE` / `.ENDIF` block completely defeats the purpose of using that.  Just use `cmp/jcc` directly to make simpler code.

Comment: You should consider to make your input BYTE array larger than one byte. Maybe `userDig db 64 dup(?)` instead of `userDig BYTE ?`.

Comment: @PeterCordes and @zx485 I tried both your reccs but they didn't change anything, unfortunately whereas yesterdays advice for the `,0` worked wonderfully it didn't today. I went ahead and added `,0` and changed it to `userDig db 64 dup (?)` but it still give me this error: `Enter a digit: Do you want to run the program again (Y or N)?`

Comment: Those fixes are necessary but not sufficient if you also have other bugs.  Like I said, use the debugger to single-step your code so you can actually see where it jumps, and look at the value in EDX.  I don't see you load from the string so presumably EDX still holds a pointer which is a number much greater than `9`.

Comment: Ran the debugger, and it stops (breakpoint) at `jmp L1` -- I rarely if ever use the debugger so I don't know what to make of this. I feel the error might be in the register EDX. However, we zero it out at the beginning...

Comment: The most useful thing to do with a debugger for this is probably to set a breakpoint early in the function.  From there, single-step one instruction (not source line) at a time to see which jumps are taken and which fall through.  Don't just stop somewhere.  Re: EDX: the very next instruction is `mov edx, OFFSET digitprompt`, and the last EDX modification before your branches is `mov edx, OFFSET userDig`.  IDK why you'd expect it to get a 0..9 value.  If this isn't clear, talk to your instructor for some 1-on-1 interactive help.  It sounds like you need some help with basic concepts.